# Composer conflicts GitHub tag with its commit hash

Tags: github, composer-php, dependency-management

When I run `composer update` with lot of packages i get this error:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for piwik/piwik dev-2491e6bfcf61984b0f0f3387e1496815e809c6cc -> satisfiable by piwik/piwik[dev-2491e6bfcf61984b0f0f3387e1496815e809c6cc].
    - myspace/MyPlugin 2.13.0 requires piwik/piwik >=2.16.0 -> satisfiable by piwik/piwik[2.16.0].
    - Can only install one of: piwik/piwik[2.16.0, dev-2491e6bfcf61984b0f0f3387e1496815e809c6cc].
    - Installation request for myspace/myplugin 2.13.0 -> satisfiable by myspace/MyPlugin[2.13.0].
```

The weird thing is that piwik tag `2.16.0` is the exact same commit as `dev-2491e6bfcf61984b0f0f3387e1496815e809c6cc`. Further more I don't see any dependent `composer.json` which requires `dev-2491e6bfcf61984b0f0f3387e1496815e809c6cc`.

This in my main `composer.json`. Repositories are defined as (https://github.com/myspace/MyPlugin.git is a fake address):

```
"repositories": {
  "myspace-myplugin": {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/myspace/MyPlugin.git"
  },
  "require": {
      "myspace/MyPlugin": "2.13.0"
  }
}
```

and dependent `composer.json` requirements of `myspace/MyPlugin`:

```
"require": {
  "piwik/piwik": ">=2.16.0",
  "php": ">=5.4"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I switched from unbounded version constraint `>=2.16.0` to range `^2.16` on `piwik/piwik` - this will install `piwik/piwik (2.16.1-b1)` atm.

I've also added `minimum-stability` `beta` because `piwik 2.16.0` has a dependency on `php-di 5.0.0-beta`, which could not be resolved at the given level of stability. We need to go lower to get beta stuff. And they should probably raise it to a stable version on their side.

Bottom-line: please try the following `composer.json`.

```
{
    "require": {
      "piwik/piwik":     "^2.16",
      "php":             ">=5.4"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "beta"
}
```

Tested & works for me.

Comment: I will give it a try.